# Not getting expected reply from telegram bot

Tags: python-3.x

I am currently making covid-info bot for telegram to be familiar with python.

To get headline from one of the news websites, I had made the web-crawling code with beautifulsoup:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


def get_headline():
    url = f'https://7news.com.au/news/coronavirus-sa'
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')
    headlines = soup.select('h2.Card-Headline')
    for h2 in headlines:
        print(h2.text)

get_headline()
```

This code gave me a result that I wanted, which was:

```
STATE OF THE NATION: Australia fighting to contain COVID as cases soar to record highs
Scott Morrison flags potential changes to COVID-19 approach after National Cabinet
WATCH LIVE: Scott Morrison provides COVID-19 update after National Cabinet meeting
Australia’s COVID cases could hit 250,000 DAILY unless restrictions return
PM’s plea ahead of emergency meeting as he declares ‘we’re not going back to lockdowns’
South Australia scraps testing rule as cases surge to all-time high
SA COVID cases surge into triple digit figures for first time 
Massive headaches at South Australian testing clinics as COVID cases surge
Revellers forced into isolation after SA teen goes clubbing while infectious with COVID
COVID scare hits Ashes Test in Adelaide after two media members test positive
SA to ease restrictions despite record number of COVID cases
‘We’re going to have cases every day’: SA records biggest COVID spike in 18 MONTHS
```

Thus, I tried to put this code into the code that I made for the telegram bot

```
from requests.api import get
from requests.models import guess_json_utf
import telegram
import requests
import re
import urllib.request
from telegram.ext import Updater, dispatcher
from telegram.ext import MessageHandler
from telegram.ext import Filters
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

def get_headline():
    url = f'https://7news.com.au/news/coronavirus-sa'
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')
    headlines = soup.select('h2.Card-Headline')
    for h2 in headlines:
        print(h2.text)

token = "-"
id = "-"

bot = telegram.Bot(token)
info_message = '''
- For recent COVID-19 related news: type News
'''
bot.sendMessage(chat_id=id, text=info_message)

updater = Updater(token=token, use_context=True)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
updater.start_polling()

def handler(update, context):
    user_text = update.message.text
    if(user_text == "News"):
        headline = get_headline()
        bot.send_message(chat_id=id, text = headline)


echo_handler = MessageHandler(Filters.text, handler)
dispatcher.add_handler(echo_handler)
```

However, this code does not return value, and returns

```
telegram.error.BadRequest: Message text is empty
```

I am wondering should I try to change the function (get_headline) or alter the codes of the reply part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this error it should not be hard to guess that `headline` doesn't contain any text. This is due to `get_headline` never returning anything - it just `print` s the text. so `headline is None`.